# What is the different between "?attr/xyz", "?android:xyz" and "?android:attr/xyz" in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Both seem to work in most cases but `?attr/` seems to have compatibility problems. I understand that `?` means we are referring to the current theme value, but what's that doesn't answer my question.

Can someone explain and also mention the best practices?

I am using a theme which inherits from Material theme for v21 and from AppCompat for lower versions. What are the complications I should look out for?

Thanks.

Comment: `?attr/` defines and referes to the value of an attribute which you have defined on your own in your application. Where as `android:attr/` referes to the values of an attribute which are already available in android built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That helps. I have modified the question to also understand how `?android:xyz` is different from the other two. Can yo u help?

Comment: @GrIsHu Does that imply `?attr/` will not fallback to android-build-in variables if I have used them so?

Comment: More specifically, the ? implies an extra level of indirection. Think of it as dereferencing an attribute to fetch the resource it points to rather than referring to the attribute itself. You see this with `?android:attr/foo`

Comment: Yes using `?attr/` does not fallback to android's built-in variable.

Comment: http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2015/02/difference-between-attr-and-androidattr.html[](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2015/02/difference-between-attr-and-androidattr.html)

Answer (score 3):

As I blogged about here:

> ### **?attr/xyz**
>
> Defines and refers to the value of an attribute which you have defined
> on your own in your application.
>
> **?android:attr/xyz**
> -------------------------- Refers to the values of an attribute which are already available in android built-in.
>
> More specifically, the **?** implies an extra level of indirection.
> Think of it as dereferencing an attribute to fetch the resource it
> points to rather than referring to the attribute itself. You see this
> with `?android:attr/foo`
>
> Which is the best practice to use is depends on what properties you
> are using and if it is available in built-in android system then you
> can use it otherwise you can define on your own.

I also answered ***What's the difference between `@android:` and `?android`?***

> **@android:** -- This is a reference to existing resource or previously declared style (or drawable or dimension, etc).
>
> **?android:** -- Is a reference to an item declared in the current Theme*. An example can show this best.  I like to think of these as
> style 'variables', or global attributes that can are set in the main
> Theme declaration.

From the article which explain about an attributes referencing in android [HERE](http://https417.blogspot.in/2014/06/answering-that-nagging-androidattr.html):

> Let's say we've got a style that's currently being applied to a stock
> Widget, the `ExpandableListView` style. For our app, we want to
> override the **groupIndicator** and the **childDivider** styles.
>
> ```
> <style name="Widget.Holo.ExpandableListView" parent="Widget.Holo.ListView">
>   <item name="groupIndicator">@android:drawable/expander_group_holo_dark</item>
>   ...
>   <item name="android:childDivider">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> **groupIndicator** is using an `@android` reference to a stock drawable.  To override this, we'll need have create a new style (that
> has a parent of `Widget.Holo.ExpandableListView`) and override the
> groupIndicator with a new drawable.  We'll then need to set the style
> on our ExpandableListView, or set the style for ExpandableListViews to
> use the new style or pass it to the style to the view directly via the
> constructor.
>
> **childDivider** is using a `?android` attribute reference.  This is a lot easier to override.  In the main app Theme, add an item that sets
> this property.

For more details check [Referencing attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml)